# How do I debug disappearing rotated elements in CSS?

Tags: css, transform

I have a card with something on the back, and I'm y-rotating the card +/- 180 deg:

http://jsfiddle.net/s46t6cem/1/

```
#back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.flipped-right {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.flipped-left {
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
```

In the jsfiddle basic example, both flips work fine. However, in my application, flipping right works, but when I flip left, I can see the back as it's moving (it flickers though, which is odd), but then I can't see the back when it stops moving. I can see it if I change the original #back rotation to 181 deg.

[image]

and then

[image]

I can't figure out what's different between the fiddle and my app that might be causing this. How can I further diagnose this?

Comment: could you provide more info about your application?

Comment: Do you have any styles in the app that are different from the JSFiddle? Hard to help you diagnose what might be going on with only working code :)

To answer your question literally -- "How do I debug this?" -- I'd start looking for differences between the JSFiddle and the app and isolate them one-by-one until you figure out which one is making it act differently.

If you have a background color / background image for the #card element in the app, that might be causing the flickering issues. If you do get down to isolating differences, I'd start by looking at #card.

Comment: Thank you, it was the `background: white` on the #card. Is that a known CSS/rendering bug?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how to debug this kind of things. But maybe you need to add some x-browser propierty:
`-webkit -moz -o -ms`. I have used this code in other project, try it, it worked for me (not for IE)

```
<style>
 .flip-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-perspective: 800;
  -moz-perspective: 800;
  -o-perspective: 800;
  -ms-perspective: 800;
  perspective: 800;
  padding: 0;
}

 .flip {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

 .flip-container:hover .flip {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

 .side {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

 .flip .front {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
 .flip .back {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
</style>

<div class="flip-container">
    <div class="flip">
        <div class="side front">
        a
        </div>
        <div class="side back">
        b
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @mknadler, I took `background: white` off of the `#card` and it works.